# Buscando um valor int em uma array de structs em C

Tags: c, array, struct, procedure

Boa noite galera, estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo em C para uma avaliação da faculdade. Se trata de um sisteminha de cadastro e consulta de aplicações de vacinas, usei uma array de structs para armazenar valores como nome da pessoa, CPF, marca da vacina, etc. A avaliação pede que o sistema permita cadastrar aplicações de vacina, listar todas as aplicações cadastradas e fazer busca de aplicações por CPF. Criei um procedimento para cada uma dessas ações que pode ser invocada ao digitar a opção que deseja no terminal, mas o procedimento de busca por CPF não está funcionando como deveria, quando digito o numero do CPF para fazer a busca ele sempre retorna "não encontrado" mesmo que o CPF esteja registrado na struct (eu verifiquei se estava). Segue abaixo o trecho referente ao procedimento.

```
void buscaCpf(struct Aplicacao x[15]) {
    int i = 0, cpf = 0;

    printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
    printf("\n\nDigite o CPF que deseja buscar(com pontuação): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &cpf);

    for(i == 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(cpf == x[i].cpf) {
            printf("\n\nAplicação encontrada:");
            printf("\nCódigo: %d", x[i].codigo);
            printf("\nNome: %s", x[i].nome);
            printf("\nCPF: %d", x[i].cpf);
            printf("\nVacina: %s", x[i].vacina);
            printf("\nData: %s", x[i].data);
            printf("\nLote: %d", x[i].lote);
            printf("\n=====================================\n");
            continue;
        } else{
            if(i == 14) {
                system("cls");
                printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
                printf("\n\nCPF não encontrado!\n");
            }

            continue;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}
```

C experts me deem um help! ;-;

Vou deixar abaixo o código completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Aplicacao {
  int codigo;
  char nome[80];
  int cpf;
  char vacina[20];
  char data[11];
  int lote;
};

void cadastro(struct Aplicacao x[15]) {
    int i = 0, tamanhoDoNome = 0;

    for(i == 0; i < 15; i++){
        tamanhoDoNome = strlen(x[i].nome);
        if(tamanhoDoNome == 0){
            x[i].codigo = i+1;
            printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
            printf("\n\nDigite o nome: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(x[i].nome);
            printf("\nDigite o CPF (sem pontuação): ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &x[i].cpf);
            printf("\nDigite a marca da vacina: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(x[i].vacina);
            printf("\nDigite a data da aplicação: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(x[i].data);
            printf("\nDigite o lote: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &x[i].lote);

            system("cls");

            printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
            printf("\nCódigo: %d", x[i].codigo);
            printf("\nNome: %s", x[i].nome);
            printf("\nCPF: %d", x[i].cpf);
            printf("\nVacina: %s", x[i].vacina);
            printf("\nData: %s", x[i].data);
            printf("\nLote: %d\n", x[i].lote);
            printf("\n=====================================\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
            } else{
                continue;
            }
    }
}

void listarAplicacoes(struct Aplicacao x[15]) {
    int i = 0, tamanhoDoNome = 0;

    printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------\n\n");
    for(i == 0; i < 15; i++){
        tamanhoDoNome = strlen(x[i].nome);
        if(tamanhoDoNome > 0){
            printf("Código: %d", x[i].codigo);
            printf("\nNome: %s", x[i].nome);
            printf("\nCPF: %d", x[i].cpf);
            printf("\nVacina: %s", x[i].vacina);
            printf("\nData: %s", x[i].data);
            printf("\nLote: %d", x[i].lote);
            printf("\n=====================================\n");
            continue;
            } else{
                continue;
            }
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

void buscaCpf(struct Aplicacao x[15]) {
    int i = 0, cpf = 0;

    printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
    printf("\n\nDigite o CPF que deseja buscar(com pontuação): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &cpf);

    for(i == 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(cpf == x[i].cpf) {
            printf("\n\nAplicação encontrada:");
            printf("\nCódigo: %d", x[i].codigo);
            printf("\nNome: %s", x[i].nome);
            printf("\nCPF: %d", x[i].cpf);
            printf("\nVacina: %s", x[i].vacina);
            printf("\nData: %s", x[i].data);
            printf("\nLote: %d", x[i].lote);
            printf("\n=====================================\n");
            continue;
        } else{
            if(i == 14) {
                system("cls");
                printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
                printf("\n\nCPF não encontrado!\n");
            }

            continue;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

int main(void) {
  struct Aplicacao Registro[15];
  int x = 0, op = 0;

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

  for (x=0; x<15; x++) {
    Registro[x].nome[0] = '\0';
  }

  do{
    printf("---------------- Sistema de vacinação ----------------");
    printf("\n\nDigite o valor correspondente à ação que deseja realizar.");
    printf("\n1 - Cadastrar Vacina");
    printf("\n2 - Listar Aplicações");
    printf("\n3 - Consultar por CPF");
    printf("\n4 - Sair\n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &op);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    switch (op) {
      case 1: cadastro(Registro);
      break;
      case 2: listarAplicacoes(Registro);
      break;
      case 3: buscaCpf(Registro);
      break;
      case 4:
      break;
      default: printf("\nOpção inválida!\n");
      system("pause");
      system("cls");
      break;

    }
  }while (op != 4);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não percebi muito bem!

```
printf("\n\nDigite o CPF que deseja buscar(com pontuação): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &cpf);
```

Eu sou de portugal nao sei o que é o CPF, mas como voce pede pontuação acho esse trecho de codigo estranho! esta a usar %d que so recebe inteiros. Se calhar o melhor é passar tudo para strings e usar o strcmp